# 'list' object is not callable: TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I have a function which is returning 2 values. When I try to fetch those values in a list in another function, it is giving the following error:

> 'list' object is not callable: TypeError

Here is the function returning two values.

```
def function(): 
    return val1, val2
```

Here is the other function calling `function()`:

```
def function1():

    values = []
    values = function()
    value_1 = values[0]
    value_2 = values[1]
```

Comment: return val1, val2 should return a tuple but I don't think it will give you this error. Please add more error info.

Comment: There is no need to define `values = []`, as you are assigning the value returned by `function()` which will be a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function()` returns two values, which cannot be stored in a single variable 'values', so instead make `function()` return a `list` of those two values

```
def function():
    return [val1,val2]
def function1():
    values=function()
    value_1=values[0]
    value_2=values[1]
```

You don't need `values=[]` since it will get overridden anyways by `values=function()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
def function():

    #return any predefined value here
    return 1, 2

def function1():
    values = []
    a,b = function()
    values.append(a)
    values.append(b)
    print(values)

function1()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: @glhr I've edited the answer to fix the intendation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not throw that exception, as the return from function is a tuple.
However here is a modified version of your code which returns a list.

```
def function():
    val1 = 10
    val2 = 20

    #return the values in a list
    return [val1, val2]

def function1():
    values = function()
    value_1 = values[0]
    value_2 = values[1]
    print(value_1, value_2)
function1()
```

Output:

```
10 20
```